# Why is IoU said to be non-differentiable?

Tags: deep-learning

I have been trying to find an answer online but I couldn't really find one. If anyone could help me I would appreciate it

Comment: Do you have a reference saying that? Maybe I'm missing some context, but intersection over union is discrete, so treating it as a function of the weights it's piecewise-constant, so of course it's not differentiable?

Answer (score 1):

Intersection over Union (IoU) can be differentiable. The paper "[UnitBox: An Advanced Object Detection Network](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.01471.pdf)" by Yu et al. describes it detail.